# Image appears next to my share at Facebook, though it shouldn't

Tags: facebook

My blog sends out as `og:image` an image 32x32 pixels, because theme used does not support featured images and there are no images in the shared article itself. Such small images are (should be) too small for Facebook to include along with share.

This is confirmed by both [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/):

[image: output from Facebook debugger]

and [Facebook Sharer](https://www.facebook.com/sharer):

[image: output from Facebook Sharer]

neither of these two contains image, when testing my share.

And so the shared post, when editing it for the first time:

[image: output from shared post]

Yet, when share post is finally made, few minutes later, scratchy, pixelized 32x32 image appears:

[image: output from final shared post]

What can be causing this and is there any way to block this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the image added by Jetpack. If it finds no image in the post it defaults to site icon.

## Remove only og:image

```
function wap_84598_remove_image_tag( $tags ) {
      unset( $tags['og:image'] );
    return $tags;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_open_graph_tags', 'wap_84598_remove_image_tag' );
```

For more details you can check this answer on [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228649/43098).